# Is it possible to convert a video to alpha channel video in ios on run time?

Tags: ios, iphone, video

I am trying to add a video in which I can remove alpha color say black color, So that it remove all the black color from that particular video. Is it possible to perform the changes on run time in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

So, the short answer is No, you will not be able to get this "working", for certain definitions of "working". What you need to actually do is shoot your original video against a green screen and then process it offline with a video editing tool to create an alpha channel video and encode both streams as H264. For a lot more detail on why that is, take a look at my [blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post18_green_screen/) on the subject.